# Why is Timber giving me a NoClassDefFoundError when trying to use the a 3 state checkbox?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, checkbox

I followed the installation instructions at [android arsenal](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/7470#!package) and was able to build the solution:

In main build.gradle:

```
repositories {
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}
```

and in app build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation 'com.github.sephiroth74:Tri-State-Checkbox:v1.0.0@aar'
    ...
}
```

But when I try to run the app I get this error:

> 2020-02-27 14:49:01.800 14357-14357/com.software.test E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.software.test, PID: 14357 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ltimber/log/Timber; at it.sephiroth.android.library.checkbox3state.CheckBox3.(CheckBox3.java:19) at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method) at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343) at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:852) at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1004) at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:959) at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1121) at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1082) at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:680) at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:532) at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:479) at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469) at androidx.

I've also tried to follow the installation instructions at his [github](https://github.com/sephiroth74/Tri-State-Checkbox#installation) repository, but I can't even get the solution to build if follow those. So for the time being I've deserted this route.

Comment: Looks like this `Tri-State-Checkbox` uses `Timber`. Do you have it in your app?

Comment: @Demigod I also put that in my dependencies and when I do the app runs fine, but there is no checkbox.

Comment: "but there is no checkbox" that is the separate topic :) leave Timber in your dependencies and find out why?

Comment: @Demigod I agree that it is a separate topic :) I've looked for any errors or anything when I leave Timber in and didn't see anything -- I'll try again though. I just didn't think that I'd have to add the dependency as it is a dependency for the library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `@aar` from your dependency declaration. This suffix means you do not want the transitive dependencies automatically pulled in as dependencies in your project, in this case, Timber. That's why you had to manually add Timber separately to get it to work.

IMO, a public library should not include a logging library dependency! An issue should be opened on the project's Github page.

Looks like the library on Github has an [open issue](https://github.com/sephiroth74/Tri-State-Checkbox/issues/1) for simply not displaying the check box at all, so if that's not fixed, you may want to look for an alternate solution.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know what that suffix meant. I have been following that issue as well as contributed to it. But thought that I might get more feed back through stackoverflow and decided to post this question.

Comment: Are you targeting lower than API 21?

Comment: No my minSdkVersion is 23 and my targetSdkVersion is 29

Comment: Removing the @aar fixed the NoClassDefFoundError. Apparently you have to have checkBox1.setChecked(false, false) as one of the first things that occurs when creating the view.